# cosine-similarity between consecutive pairs using whole articles in JSON file

Tags: python, tf-idf

I would like to calculate the cosine similarity for the consecutive pairs of articles in a JSON file. So far I manage to do it but.... I just realize that when transforming the tfidf of each article I am not using the terms from all articles available in the file but only those from each pair. Here is the code that I am using which provides the cosine-similarity coefficient of each consecutive pair of articles.

```
import json
import nltk
with open('SDM_2015.json') as f:
    data = [json.loads(line) for line in f]

## Loading the packages needed:
import nltk, string
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

## Defining our functions to filter the data

# Short for stemming each word (common root)
stemmer = nltk.stem.porter.PorterStemmer()

# Short for removing puctuations etc
remove_punctuation_map = dict((ord(char), None) for char in string.punctuation)

## First function that creates the tokens
def stem_tokens(tokens):
    return [stemmer.stem(item) for item in tokens]

## Function that incorporating the first function, converts all words into lower letters and removes puctuations maps (previously specified)
def normalize(text):
    return stem_tokens(nltk.word_tokenize(text.lower().translate(remove_punctuation_map)))

## Lastly, a super function is created that contains all the previous ones plus stopwords removal
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=normalize, stop_words='english')

## Calculation one by one of the cosine similatrity

def foo(x, y):
    tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform([x, y])
    return ((tfidf * tfidf.T).A)[0,1]

my_funcs = {}
for i in range(len(data) - 1):
    x = data[i]['body']
    y = data[i+1]['body']
    foo.func_name = "cosine_sim%d" % i
    my_funcs["cosine_sim%d" % i] = foo
    print(foo(x,y))
```

Any idea of how to develop the cosine-similarity using the whole terms of all articles available in the JSON file rather than only those of each pair?

Kind regards,

Andres

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you want to do is first calculate the TFIDF for each term in each article independently.  the IDF is over the entire corpus.  Then using the TFIDF, calculate the similarity between the documents.  Is that your question?

Comment: @flyingmeatball . Yes that is right, and actually the code gives me already the cosine-similarity of the consecutive pairs. Since the tfidf is formed by the idf, all corpus, I am not sure what my corpus is here: a pair of articles or all the articles in my document.

Comment: Your corpus is all articles.  If a given word in two consecutive articles is "rare" among all articles, it should then be reflected in the TFIDF value for that word, and the articles should appear closer together based on your similarity metric because they both include a relatively rare word.

Comment: thanks very much for your answer, so you think that in the way this is programmed, the TFIDF is composed using all articles and not just the relevant pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, based on our discussion above, you need to change the foo function and everything below.  See the code below.  Note that I haven't actually run this, since I don't have your data and no sample lines are provided.

```
## Loading the packages needed:
import nltk, string
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine
import json
from  sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

with open('SDM_2015.json') as f:
    data = [json.loads(line) for line in f]

## Defining our functions to filter the data

# Short for stemming each word (common root)
stemmer = nltk.stem.porter.PorterStemmer()

# Short for removing puctuations etc
remove_punctuation_map = dict((ord(char), None) for char in string.punctuation)

## First function that creates the tokens
def stem_tokens(tokens):
    return [stemmer.stem(item) for item in tokens]

## Function that incorporating the first function, converts all words into lower letters and removes puctuations maps (previously specified)
def normalize(text):
    return stem_tokens(nltk.word_tokenize(text.lower().translate(remove_punctuation_map)))

## tfidf
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=normalize, stop_words='english')
tfidf_data = vectorizer.fit_transform(data)

#cosine dists
similarity matrix  = cosine_similarity(tfidf_data)
```